# how to solve the error MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.admins index: status_1 dup key: { status: "true" }

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, nestjs

here is my shcema file.

```
  name:{type:String,unique:true,required:true},
  email:{type:String,unique:true,required:true},
  userName:{type:String,unique:true,required:true},
  password:{type:String,unique:true,required:true},
  status:{type:String,unique:true,default:true}
},{timestamps:true})
```

And i'm converting the password in to bcrypt

Comment: it's not enough to provide a schema and say that there is an exception. You should provide what you tried/considered/your thoughts too.

Comment: Do you have `status` really unique?

Comment: thank you i got the error where i'm stuck thank you]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the unique property in status. If you declare `unique` to `true` all the fields must have the `unique` value. The value of status will be either `true` or `false`. So duplication will occur.

**Use this schema**:

```js
name: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
email: {
  type: String,
  unique: true,
  required: true
},
userName: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
password: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
status: {
  type:String,
  default:true
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can add `.clone()` after your MongoDB query, this will remove the E11000 duplicate key error

Comment: Never heart about this command. There **was** a command `db.cloneCollection()` but no idea why this would solve the problem.

Comment: Both are the same
Have a look at this https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/command/clone/

Comment: MongoDB version 4.0 is End-Of-Life